# Client Side IPEndPoint can't use IPAddress.Any?

Tags: c#, asyncsocket

I have been learning some socket programming, i have created an asynchornous server which is only listen and return the data.

but i have a problem here, I use IPEndPoint on server with IPEndPoint(IPAddress.any,port), and I do the same with the client side. When running the server and client, I use try catch and the client side returning its exception like this

"The requested address is not valid in its context 0.0.0.0:port"

here below is the code:

Server.cs

```
      Public void Listen()
      {
        IPEndPoint IpEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000);

        Console.WriteLine("Create new socket");
        mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                       SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.IP);

        Console.WriteLine("Bind the socket");
        mainSocket.Bind(IpEnd);

        Console.WriteLine("Listening to socket");
        mainSocket.Listen(10);

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting Connection");
        mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConnect), null);
      }
      protected void AcceptConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
      {
        try
        {
            Socket client = mainSocket.EndAccept(ar);
            SessionData session = new SessionData();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Accepted, waiting for Data");
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting a new Connection");
            mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConnect), null);
            try{
                session.clientSocket = client;
                client.BeginReceive(session.buffer,0,SessionData.buffersize,0, 
                                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), session);
            }catch(Exception e){
                client.Send(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(e.Message));
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
      }
```

Client.cs

```
    public void ClientConnect()
    {

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000);

        // Connect to the remote endpoint.
        client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectServer), client);
    }
    public void ConnectServer(IAsyncResult ar) 
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}", 
                             client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

my question is :

1. Does client need to point at one IPAddress?
2. Am I just using the wrong code on the server?

Comment: Yes, client needs a specific endpoint to connect to.  On a server, 0.0.0.0 means "listen on any possible interface" but as a client  you must state who you are trying to connect to.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks for the answer Joe, but even if i changed the IP it still give me error,  "the connection failed because the connection party didn't properly respond or failed to respond", what is the problem now?

Comment: @JohnSaunders ok then, sorry for the wrong titles... and thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client needs to point to a specific IP address (i.e. 192.168.1.101 or something similar), you can't send packets to IP 0.0.0.0. The reason that the server can accept IP.Any is that it's listening on all IP address on the local machine, which is represented at 0.0.0.0.

Comment: so, in the end client can't use IPAddress.Any? Ok then, i think, thats my answer gonna try to change the IP then. Will post here the result of it.

Comment: OK, I changed the IP address to the 192.168.0.101, its give me an error said that "the connection failed because the connection party didn't properly respond or failed to respond". So whats the problem here?

Comment: Does the server machine actually have the IP address 192.168.0.101?

Comment: well, i been using the same computer as the server to try it out, so it shouldn't be a problem right??

Comment: Well the IP address needs to be what the IP of the server is. So if the client and server are on the same machine then it needs to be that machines IP address.

Comment: So thats why! OK then, thank you for your time @Zipper. Its help me a lot.